# Can't clear markers from MarkerClusterGroup

Tags: leaflet, clustering, plugins

i have problems removing all markers befor adding new ones.

```
  var L_Emergency_Access_Points = L.markerClusterGroup(); 
  var EapMarkers = L.geoJson(null,merge_options(globalOverlayOptions,
               { name:          "EapMarkers"
                ,onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                                   layer.bindPopup("hallo")
                                }
               })
            );

... snip ...

map.on("moveend") {
   bbox = map.getBounds().getSouth().toFixed(5) +","+  map.getBounds().getWest().toFixed(5) +","
        + map.getBounds().getNorth().toFixed(5) +","+  map.getBounds().getEast().toFixed(5);

    $.ajax({
           url: geosWFS,
           async: false,
           data: {
                   service : "WFS",
                   version : "1.1.0",
                   request : "GetFeature",
              outputFormat : "application/json",
                   SrsName : "EPSG:4326",
                   typeName: "osm:Emergency Access Points",
                       bbox: bbox
           },
           datatype: "json",
            success: function(data,text,xhr) {
                       console.log(myLocalName, "success");

                       EapMarkers.clearLayers(); // problem ????
                       map.removeLayer(L_Emergency_Access_Points);

                       $(data.features).each(function(key, data) {
                          EapMarkers.addData(data);
                       });

                       L_Emergency_Access_Points.addLayer(EapMarkers);
                       map.addLayer(L_Emergency_Access_Points);
                    }
        });
});
```

after loading page:

[image: initial load of page]

after litte panning to trigger "on moveend":

[image: after little panning]

reload data is triggered by "on moveend" and it is working fine. But it does not clear the old data. every pan the new markers are added without removing the old ones.

btw: can't add more images :( your restrictions to new users are not helpfull. :(

Any idea?

EDIT: Got it by replacing success block:

```
                     success: function(data,text,xhr) {
                             console.log(myLocalName, "success");

                             L_Emergency_Access_Points.clearLayers();
                             map.removeLayer(L_Emergency_Access_Points);

                             var markerList = [];
                             $(data.features).each(function(key, data) {
                                var marker = L.marker(L.latLng(data.geometry.coordinates[1],
                                                               data.geometry.coordinates[0]),
                                            { title: "hallo" } );
                                marker.bindPopup("hallo");
                                markerList.push(marker);
                             });

                             L_Emergency_Access_Points.addLayers(markerList);
                             map.addLayer(L_Emergency_Access_Points);
                          }
```

Comment: You should add your Edit as an answer to this question (explaining better what you did to solve the problem).

Comment: Yes, would you please do that, with explanation, to help others who read this question in future? Thanks. Btw, it is perfectly fine to accept your own answer - marking it as correct will help others.